# SimpleXML adding childs and attributes for excel

Tags: php, xml, excel, simplexml

I'n really new to this and my question should be simple. Lets say i have this xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    ....
        xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    ....
    <Worksheet ss:Name="sheet1">
    ....
    <Worksheet ss:Name="sheet2">
    ....
```

How do i add in worksheet 1 a cell in row 5 looking like this:

```
    <Cell ss:Index="5" ss:StyleID="s22"><Data ss:Type="String">Some text</Data></Cell>
```

using SimpleXML?
Anyone with sample of code, please.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to [retrieve the node](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) you need using a Location Path and then, after you construct the [new element](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php), you can use the method [addchild](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php).

Comment: Thanks Aurelio, but I've been reading thruogh php.net for two days and i just can't understand everything. Can you give me an example?